# Terminal size in terminfo not being honoured

Tags: linux, debian, terminal

I have a (custom, I've built it myself) serial terminal connected to a Raspberry Pi running Debian Linux. The screen size is a non-standard size, so I specify the terminal size in my terminfo file.

```
wp1,
    am,
    cols#91, lines#15,
    bel=^G, clear=\032$<1/>, cr=\r, cud1=\n, cuf1=^L,
    cup=\E=%p1%' '%+%c%p2%' '%+%c, cuu1=^K, dl1=\ER, ed=^W,
    el=^X, home=^^, il1=\EE, ind=\n, kcud1=\n, kcuf1=^L, kcuu1=^K,
```

I then compile and install it with `tic`, and do `setenv TERM=wp1`.

The terminfo file is being picked up, but programs still think the terminal size is 80x24. As does `stty size`, and `tput cols` / `tput lines`. Clearly something, somewhere, thinks it knows better than I do and is overriding the values in the terminfo file. What, and how can I stop it?

Comment: "Overriding" implies there's anything that would _read_ the values from the terminfo file in the first place. That isn't necessarily the case.

Answer (score 0):

Serial connections assume that the geometry is 80x23 or 80x24.

You may use for (only) your current terminal session:

```
stty rows 15 cols 91
```

See also
[Working with the serial console - Resizing a terminal](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Working_with_the_serial_console#Resizing_a_terminal).